# Questions about proving the statement: $\tau(\omega)$ is a stopping time, iff $\{ \tau(\omega) < t\}$ $\in \mathcal{F}_t$, for all $t \geq 0$.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times, filtrations

Assume the filtration is right-continuous ($\mathcal{F}_{t+0} := \cap_{s>t}\mathcal{F_s} = \mathcal{F}_t$) and complete, then we have that $\tau(\omega)$ is a stopping time, if and only if $\{ \tau(\omega) < t\}$ $\in \mathcal{F}_t$, for all $t \geq 0$.

Here is the proof:

$\Rightarrow$: $\{ \tau(\omega) < t\}$ = $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{ \tau(\omega)\leq t- 1/n\} \in \mathcal{F}_t;$

The "$\in$" is truth due to the definition of stopping time and the definition of sigma algebra; that is $\{ \tau(\omega)\leq t- 1/n\} \in \mathcal{F}_{t-1/n} \subset \mathcal{F}_t$ for all $n$, then the union is in $\mathcal{F_t}$.

$\Leftarrow$: $\{ \tau(\omega) \leq t\}$ = $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \{ \tau(\omega) < t+ 1/n\} \in \mathcal{F}_{t+0} = \mathcal{F}_t;$

One question is that:

The last equality follows from our right continuous assumption, but the why the "$\in$" is the case?

Another question is that:

Many books give the statement $\cap_{s>t}\mathcal{F_s} = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_{t+1/n}$, but they don't provide any proof of it, I've tried to prove it, but it doesn't make sense to me. can you give any thought about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalently, $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \{ \tau(\omega) < t+ 1/n\} \in \mathcal{F}_s$$ for every $s > t$, which is implied by, since $\{ \tau(\omega) < t+ 1/n\}$ is a decreasing sequence of events, that $\{ \tau(\omega) < t+ 1/n\} \in \mathcal{F}_s$ for all $n > N$ for some $N$.  To see this just set $N = 1/(s-t)$.

---

For the second question,
$$\bigcap_{s>t}\mathcal{F_s} \subseteq \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_{t+1/n}$$ follows immediately from the fact that $t+1/n > t$ so the left intersection is over more sets.

The other direction is the archimedean property.  Fix $s > t$.  Then there is some positive integer $m$ such that $t+1/m < s$ showing $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_{t+1/n} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{t+1/m} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_s.$$ Now just intersect over all $s>t$.

Comment: i've been thinking this question for a long time, you save me, thanks!